# Уместность употребления слова "брутальный" в произведении бытового красноречия

Tags: коммуникативные-требования

Один высокопоставленный чиновник на дне рождения олигарха  сказал в торжественном тосте про юбиляра, что тот «…настоящий брутальный мужик. И троекратное ему ура!». Насколько уместно употребление  слова "брутальный" в данном контексте? Можно ли рассматривать его как комплимент?

Comment: Произведение красноречия?

Comment: Тосты относятся к жанрам бытового красноречия. Отдельный тост - произведение. Ну, а вопрос о качестве - это отдельно. У Ильфа и Петрова есть определение "маловысокохудожественный")))

Comment: А-а, понял теперь. Не мог сообразить, что есть такой смысл, а не только процесс.)

Comment: Красноречие - как вид деятельности, а не положительная оценка говорения.

Answer (score 1):

В субкультуре высокопоставленных чиновников это слово можно рассматривать как комплимент.  В большинстве же прочих контекстов слово "брутальный", то есть грубый, сближающий со зверем, положительно звучать не может.

Comment: Вопрос, понятно, не корректен тем,что расплывчат. Но ответ никак таким быть не может. Аргументы, обоснования, ссылки...

Answer (score 1):

> Один высокопоставленный чиновник на дне рождения олигарха сказал в
>   торжественном тосте про юбиляра, что тот «…настоящий брутальный мужик.
>   И троекратное ему ура!». Насколько уместно употребление слова
>   "брутальный" в данном контексте? Можно ли рассматривать его как
>   комплимент?

Ну а почему бы и нет? Главное, чтобы слушатели восприняли это как комплимент.

Слово *брутальный* сейчас употребляют во многих значениях, а не только в значениях *грубый, жестокий, зверский,* фиксируемых большинством словарей. И никуда от этого не денешься. К примеру, [**словарь Тришина**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/11909/%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) приводит и такие синонимы к этому слову: *мачо, мужественный, харизматический, шикарный…*

[**Из интервью с Пугачёвой:**](https://books.google.ru/books?id=ze81CwAAQBAJ&pg=PT191&dq=%22%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B6%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH6pe_tIDYAhUpQZoKHd8UC3kQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B6%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%22&f=false)

> Собчак: *Вы можете сказать, что Максим Галкин – это **брутальный**
>   мужчина?*
>
> Пугачева: *Конечно. Для меня.*
>
> Собчак: *Что тогда «брутальный» в вашем понимании?*
>
> Пугачева: *Максим Галкин – это интеллигентный, мудрый не по годам,
>   добрый, начитанный, любящий мужчина.*

А вот какое понимание слова *брутальный* встретилось [**здесь:**](https://books.google.ru/books?id=YZK_DgAAQBAJ&pg=PT425&dq=%22%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BA%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjn8MGGuIDYAhWGZpoKHWLECngQ6AEINzAD#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BA%22&f=false)

> *И не просто мужик, а **брутальный мужик** – каменюка, с твёрдым характером, стойкий и настырный.*

Чем не комплимент?

Comment: В данном случае мы имеем яркий пример агнонима (в терминологии профессора В.В. Морковкина)